# Is there any option to get column names in empty table mysql pdo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can anyone please let me know the solution for getting the column names from empty table in MySQL using pdo php?

Comment: No it didn't get me in a empty table?

Comment: Show what you tried please.

Comment: array_keys($this->Conn->query("SELECT * FROM $table LIMIT 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); this is what i tried @droopsnoot and my table is absolutely empty, there is no rows recorded in it, but I'm in  a situation to fetch column details from that table using pdo

Comment: But if you read the first answer from the linked thread, it shows you how to use the DESCRIBE keyword to get the table description, including column names.